# How do I seed Identity roles in ASP.NET Core 2.2 using Script-Migration?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using migrations to create and seed my database. Since my database is running on a separate server from my web application, I'm using Script-Migration to generate a script that I can run on the database server.

According to the official [EF Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding), we can use HasData to configure seed data for our entities. Is there a way to do this with Identity roles or users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For seeding data by `HasData`, it is usually used for your own defined model.

For seeding data for `IdentityUser` or `IdentityRole`, it is recommended to use `UserManager<IdentityUser>` and `RoleManager<IdentityRole>`. This is due to that there are many properties may not set correctly by `HasData` like `PasswordHash` and `ConcurrencyStamp`.

Check this issue [How to seed the ASP.NET Identity model, and related seeding questions #736](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/736)

Comment: Is there no code equivalent that I can insert into `OnModelCreating` of my DbContext that performs the same action as `RoleManager<IdentityRole>.CreateAsync()`? My objective is to have the database completely seeded in one action. (i.e. running one script)

Comment: @Tony Not sure whether you check the link carefully, if you insist on seeding the Identity data with `HasData`, follow [suggestion](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/736#issuecomment-394509597)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly. I meant having the data seeded with columns such as `PasswordHash` and `ConcurrencyStamp` generated automatically, similar to what calling `RoleManager<IdentityRole>.CreateAsync()` would do.

Though from the linked issue, there doesn't seem to be such a method, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/736#issuecomment-450552201).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in OnModelCreating() method. Note that keys have to be predefined to avoid seeding new roles everytime the method is executed. Below code will create a new user and a new role, and associate the role to the user:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Seeding a  'Administrator' role to AspNetRoles table
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole {Id = "2c5e174e-3b0e-446f-86af-483d56fd7210", Name = "Administrator", NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR".ToUpper() });


        //a hasher to hash the password before seeding the user to the db
        var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();


        //Seeding the User to AspNetUsers table
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(
            new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = "8e445865-a24d-4543-a6c6-9443d048cdb9", // primary key
                UserName = "myuser",
                NormalizedUserName = "MYUSER",
                PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "Pa$$w0rd")
            }
        );


        //Seeding the relation between our user and role to AspNetUserRoles table
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(
            new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = "2c5e174e-3b0e-446f-86af-483d56fd7210", 
                UserId = "8e445865-a24d-4543-a6c6-9443d048cdb9"
            }
        );
        

    }
```